# How do I implement OpenID connect in a Spring Security Authorization Server?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, openid-connect

I've got an Authorization Server running using Spring boot security and spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure shim jar.

I would like to implement the openid scope and provide identity tokens back to my clients.

Is there a way to do this currently using Spring libraries?

thanks

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect

Comment: this shows how to set-up an openid connect client using google as the auth server. I want to enhance my spring security oauth auth server to be an openid connect one too.

Comment: If you can't wait for Spring Security 5 to ship [this feature](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Features-Matrix), have a look at [MITRE](https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server) or [Authlete](https://medium.com/@darutk/spring-oauth-2-0-openid-connect-3341a6ed1f92) implementations